# 32 bit Java on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit

Will Sun Java 6 Update 30 (32 bit version) work on Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bit version)?

I should use Sun instead of OpenJDK because the support people for the API I am interfacing to referred me to Sun.  I should use the 32 bit Java 6 because Sun/Oracle's website says that it is to be used if you are using a Web Start application.  (It appears that my Java code talks to an API that is offered by a Web Start application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running 64 bit Java on a 64 bit system and the JNLP still seems to download and launch the application properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so then use the 32-bit version. I don't see why it wouldn't work. You can run 32-bit programs on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.